# iPhone/iPad hover event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use jQuery to attach a listener onto my navigation so that I can show :hover effects on apple touch devices.

I cant seem to get it too work with what I have so far, has anybody used this before?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //ipad and iphone fix
        if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
             $("#primary-navigation li a").bind('touchstart', function(){
                console.log("touch started");
             });

             $("#primary-navigation li a").bind('touchend', function(){
                console.log("touch ended");
             });
        }
    });
</script>
```

---

I've added an alert just before my selectors which seems to work...

Comment: Which part doesn't work, the browser detection, the event binding or the `console.log`? Do you get an error message, or...?

Comment: The hover doesnt seem to work still, I dont get an error in my console. Within my <a> tags I do have cufon rendering text so could that be the problem?

Comment: You've got an extra `});` after the second `console.log()` - is that just a typo in your question, or is your _real_ code like that?

Comment: Sorry thats a typo in my question

Comment: OK, well try adding a `console.log() or alert()` immediately after the `if` (before the event binding) to at least confirm that the `if` works (speaking of which, you can do that test with a single regular expression). And edit your question to fix the typo.

Comment: Alert works if its a touch device, ive tried changing my selectors to
$("nav#primary-navigation ul li a") only it still doesnt seem to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you're on jQuery prior to 1.4.3 try to bind events with [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of `.bind()`. This will ensure that you will bind to that event even for future, dynamically-injected new elements responding to the selector match.

If you're on jQuery 1.4.3+ but earlier than 1.7 use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of `.bind()`.

If you're on jQuery 1.7+ then use `.on()`.

That said, if your test is taking place on iPhone or iPad, use `alert()` instead of console.log(), as you hardly could check `console` outputs on those devices.

I can also point out that the markup breakdown you posted is broken, as you have a `</cufon` element missing the '>' character. It seems this could be a copy-paste issue.

Finally, I can see you're using touch* events; I must assume you are on jQuery Mobile, jQTouch or something?

Because if you're not on one of those, I strongly doubt that you could register listeners for touch events, as basic jQuery doesn't have a representation for them in its own API.

Answer (score 0):

I've added an alert...

```
$("nav#primary-navigation ul li a").bind('touchstart', function(){
    console.log("touch started");
alert('clicked');       
});
```

Which works when clicked so i know im targeting everything correctly, is there now a way to disable the link click on ul li a?